# Group row items in pivot table according to date value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet like this:

```
NAME    DATE        CITY
John    05/12/1978  Detroit
Mark    09/11/1987  Detroit
Chris   18/10/1982  Detroit
Dave    20/04/1990  New York
```

My Pivot Table looks like this (with row fields):

```
[-] Detroit
    John
    Mark
    Chris
[-] New York
    Dave
```

I want to write a macro to group the names according to their date:

```
[-] Detroit
    [-] Dates before 04/05/1981
        John
    [-] Dates after 04/05/1981
        Mark
        Chris
[-] New York
    [-] Dates before 04/05/1981
    [-] Dates after 04/05/1981
        Dave
```

To create the "before" group, I'm trying to do this:

```
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim City As PivotItem
Dim MyDate As PivotItem
Dim r As Range

Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Worksheet1").PivotTables("Dynamic table1")

For Each City In PvtTbl.PivotFields("CITY").PivotItems
    For Each MyDate In City.PivotFields("DATE").PivotItems      ' ERROR HERE
        If MyDate.Value < DateValue("04/05/1981") Then
            If Not r Is Nothing Then
                Set r = Union(r, MyDate.DataRange)
            Else
                Set r = MyDate.DataRange
            r.Select
            End If
        End If
        r.Group
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried -  hit record macro, set up the table the way that you want it, stop recording, then go in and edit your macro so that it doesn't use the specifics of the clicks you made but can be applied to your intended targets? You should get the "guts" of your code done for you and just require some tweaks that way.

Comment: When grouping dates in pivot tables it's often much easier to use a helper column in the source data. In this case you'd add a formula to check whether the date is before of after your date of interest and then use that field in your pivot table.

Comment: I ended up using that solution, @doug. It works flawlessly, thanks.